# set a default workspace so it's not change base on blender file

Tags: workspaces

how can I set a default workspace so that when I open any Blender project from anywhere, the workspace doesn't change?

for **example**: I want my workspace **always be like this**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrange the workspace like you want it to be, go to *File* > *Defaults* > *Save Startup File*.

[image: startup file]

Now that you've changed your default workspace, when you now open a file through the *Open* dialogue, there you can bring up the options side panel with <kbd>N</kbd>, there you can disable the *Load UI* option. This way, your workspace does not change. Unfortunately you have to do this every time you open a file.

[image: load ui]

.........................

i find a way to disable **load UI** permanently.

from preferences - save & load - load ui.
[image]

Comment: thank u, but it's not what i'm looking for. for example, if u send me a blend file, when i open it on my computer, workspaces changes.

Comment: I see. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thank you, ❤️❤️

Comment: Oh, stupid me... yeah, you can set it in the preferences  :D